# Can we generate same set Random Nos given the same seed within a given range

Tags: c#

Suppose i have a seed x, and i want to generate a list of random no within a range  from a to b using c# built in class.
Will the same seed x at a later time generate the same list of random no that were generated previously ?
If no the how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [online documentation for the Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ctssatww) states, yes, if your seed is the same, you will generate the same sequence of pseudo-random values.

Answer (score 2):

yes, same seeds generates always the same randoms

Comment: That answer was in the exact same second and nearly matching :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Same seed generates same random sequence.